# Is it possible to change the color of progressBar() in ShinyWidgets to a custom color?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I would like to change the progressBar() color from shinyWidgets to a custom colour. I am aware that there are a number of default colours that can be changed with *status*, but I would like to change it to a colour that is not available.

I am quite a newbie to CSS, so I checked [here](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/blob/master/R/progressBars.R) on the git repository itself to see if I can overwrite the CSS. I tried to overwrite the CSS with (added it just before progressBar()):

```
tagss$style('.progress-bar-status{color: #25c484;
                background-color: #25c484;}')
```

But it didn't work. 
Does anyone have any idea how this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducible app, so that it's easier to test/demonstrate solutions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom `status` and define the corresponding CSS like this :

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 7,
    tags$b("Other options"), br(),
    progressBar(
      id = "pb2",
      value = 0,
      total = 100,
      title = "",
      display_pct = TRUE, 
      status = "custom"
    ),
    tags$style(".progress-bar-custom {background-color: #25c484;}"),
    actionButton(
      inputId = "go",
      label = "Launch calculation"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    for (i in 1:100) {
      updateProgressBar(
        session = session,
        id = "pb2",
        value = i, total = 100
      )
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: When clicking on "Launch calculation" I get the following error: `Warning: Error in updateProgressBar: unused argument (title = paste("Process", trunc(i/10)))`

Comment: Update the package ? Which version do you use ?

Comment: `shinyWidgets_0.4.1`

Comment: Thanks, oups I use the dev version, my bad, I edit my answer to remove this argument

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution almost works, however you should modify the property of the `progress-bar` class, e.g.:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.progress-bar {background-color: red;}')))
```

I found this out by taking the example from [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html) and modifying the `Sys.sleep` statement to 60 seconds so we can more easily inspect the page.

A working example is given below, hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$goPlot # Re-run when button is clicked

    # Create 0-row data frame which will be used to store data
    dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))

    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      # Number of times we'll go through the loop
      n <- 10

      for (i in 1:n) {
        # Each time through the loop, add another row of data. This is
        # a stand-in for a long-running computation.
        dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)))

        # Increment the progress bar, and update the detail text.
        incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Doing part", i))

        # Pause for 0.1 seconds to simulate a long computation.
        Sys.sleep(0.5)
      }
    })

    plot(dat$x, dat$y)
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(basicPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.progress-bar {background-color: red;}'))),
  plotOutput('plot', width = "300px", height = "300px"),
  actionButton('goPlot', 'Go plot')
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```